# Random mongod process termination during high disk IO

Tags: linux, mongodb

I have a 3 node mongo setup (incl 1 arbiter). The master crashed with the following log

```
2021-08-29T08:24:09.754+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18690] end connection <self>:54250 (57 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.798+0530 W EXECUTOR [conn18767] Terminating session due to error: InternalError: failed to create service entry worker thread
2021-08-29T08:24:09.798+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] end connection <mongos router 1>:57596 (56 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.798+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from <mongos router 1>:57600 #18768 (57 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.798+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from <mongos router 1>:57602 #18769 (58 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.807+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18769] received client metadata from <mongos router 1>:57602 conn18769: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-TaskExecutorPool-5", version: "3.6.5" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel 4.9.0-12-amd64" } }
2021-08-29T08:24:09.807+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18768] received client metadata from <mongos router 1>:57600 conn18768: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-TaskExecutorPool-5", version: "3.6.5" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel 4.9.0-12-amd64" } }
2021-08-29T08:24:09.808+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from <mongos router 1>:57604 #18770 (59 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.808+0530 I -        [listener] pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
2021-08-29T08:24:09.808+0530 W EXECUTOR [conn18770] Terminating session due to error: InternalError: failed to create service entry worker thread
2021-08-29T08:24:09.808+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] end connection <mongos router 1>:57604 (58 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.809+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from <mongos router 1>:57608 #18771 (59 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.810+0530 I -        [listener] pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
2021-08-29T08:24:09.810+0530 W EXECUTOR [conn18771] Terminating session due to error: InternalError: failed to create service entry worker thread
2021-08-29T08:24:09.810+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] end connection <mongos router 1>:57608 (58 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.810+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from <mongos router 1>:57610 #18772 (59 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.810+0530 I -        [listener] pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
2021-08-29T08:24:09.810+0530 W EXECUTOR [conn18772] Terminating session due to error: InternalError: failed to create service entry worker thread
2021-08-29T08:24:09.810+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] end connection <mongos router 1>:57610 (58 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.811+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from <mongos router 1>:57614 #18773 (59 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.811+0530 I -        [listener] pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
2021-08-29T08:24:09.811+0530 W EXECUTOR [conn18773] Terminating session due to error: InternalError: failed to create service entry worker thread
2021-08-29T08:24:09.811+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] end connection <mongos router 1>:57614 (58 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.815+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18768] end connection <mongos router 1>:57600 (57 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.816+0530 I SHARDING [ConfigServerCatalogCacheLoader-1957] Cache loader found no enqueued metadata and persisted metadata from 1|0||5f6f678bf026d03bea132071 to 1|0||5f6f678bf026d03bea132071, GTE cache version 1|0||5f6f678bf026d03bea132071
2021-08-29T08:24:09.818+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18769] end connection <mongos router 1>:57602 (56 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.828+0530 I SHARDING [ConfigServerCatalogCacheLoader-1957] Refresh for collection config.system.sessions took 10686 ms and found version 1|0||5f6f678bf026d03bea132071
2021-08-29T08:24:09.830+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from <mongos router 1>:57616 #18774 (57 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:09.979+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18774] received client metadata from <mongos router 1>:57616 conn18774: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-TaskExecutorPool-5", version: "3.6.5" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel 4.9.0-12-amd64" } }
2021-08-29T08:24:10.178+0530 I COMMAND  [conn18774] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1, hangUpOnStepDown: false, client: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-TaskExecutorPool-5", version: "3.6.5" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel 4.9.0-12-amd64" } }, compression: [ "snappy" ], internalClient: { minWireVersion: 6, maxWireVersion: 6 }, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:916 locks:{} protocol:op_query 335ms
2021-08-29T08:24:10.545+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from <mongos router 1>:57618 #18775 (58 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:10.852+0530 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-TaskExecutorPool-0-0] Connecting to <self>:27101
2021-08-29T08:24:11.593+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from <mongos router 1>:57620 #18776 (59 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:12.857+0530 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 75, after asserts: 95, after backgroundFlushing: 132, after connections: 132, after dur: 132, after extra_info: 222, after globalLock: 222, after locks: 222, after logicalSessionRecordCache: 222, after network: 222, after opLatencies: 222, after opcounters: 222, after opcountersRepl: 222, after repl: 222, after shardingStatistics: 258, after storageEngine: 268, after tcmalloc: 512, after transactions: 557, after wiredTiger: 1088, at end: 2610 }
2021-08-29T08:24:13.071+0530 I -        [listener] pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
2021-08-29T08:24:13.301+0530 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to <slave 1>:27101
2021-08-29T08:24:13.387+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18746] end connection <mongos router 2>:59606 (58 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:13.897+0530 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to <slave 1>:27101 - HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2021-08-29T08:24:14.241+0530 W EXECUTOR [conn18776] Terminating session due to error: InternalError: failed to create service entry worker thread
2021-08-29T08:24:14.289+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18775] received client metadata from <mongos router 1>:57618 conn18775: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-TaskExecutorPool-5", version: "3.6.5" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel 4.9.0-12-amd64" } }
2021-08-29T08:24:14.437+0530 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections to <slave 1>:27101 due to failed operation on a connection
2021-08-29T08:24:14.753+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] end connection <mongos router 1>:57620 (57 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:15.231+0530 I WRITE    [conn18762] update db command: { q: { key: "key" }, u: { $addToSet: { members: { $each: [ "random" ] } }, $set: { key: "key", type: "set" }, $currentDate: { updatedAt: true }, $setOnInsert: { createdAt: new Date(1630205628461) } }, multi: false, upsert: true } planSummary: IXSCAN { key: 1 } exception: Resulting document after update is larger than 16777216 code:Location17419 numYields:0 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } 5384ms
2021-08-29T08:24:15.438+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from <self>:57926 #18777 (58 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:15.262+0530 I REPL_HB  [replexec-210] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 2433588) to <slave 1>:27101, response status: HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2021-08-29T08:24:15.372+0530 I WRITE    [conn18750] update db command: { q: { key: "key" }, u: { $addToSet: { members: { $each: [ "random" ] } }, $set: { key: "key", type: "set" }, $currentDate: { updatedAt: true }, $setOnInsert: { createdAt: new Date(1630205635632) } }, multi: false, upsert: true } planSummary: IXSCAN { key: 1 } exception: Resulting document after update is larger than 16777216 code:Location17419 numYields:0 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4, w: 4 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 4 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 3 } }, oplog: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } 5586ms
2021-08-29T08:24:15.450+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18777] received client metadata from <self>:57926 conn18777: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-TaskExecutorPool-0", version: "3.6.5" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel 4.9.0-12-amd64" } }
2021-08-29T08:24:15.791+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18676] end connection <mongos router 2>:59408 (57 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:15.862+0530 F -        [replexec-210] terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information
2021-08-29T08:24:15.933+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18755] end connection <mongos router 2>:59632 (56 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:15.933+0530 I NETWORK  [conn18739] end connection <mongos router 3>:45060 (55 connections now open)
2021-08-29T08:24:17.303+0530 W NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Failed to connect to <slave 2>:27103, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: No route to host
2021-08-29T08:24:17.810+0530 F -        [replexec-210] std::exception::what(): Resource temporarily unavailable
Actual exception type: std::system_error

 0x5578e25e8a41 0x5578e25e8425 0x5578e26dd616 0x5578e26dd661 0x5578e1e0256f 0x5578e1e02dc8 0x5578e20a019c 0x5578e20a0602 0x5578e20a2a79 0x5578e20a2b8c 0x5578e1509c4b 0x5578e150b1cb 0x5578e209bd76 0x5578e209f523 0x5578e209fa0b 0x5578e1dfed5c 0x5578e1dff25c 0x5578e1dffc46 0x5578e26f8770 0x7f86e0e274a4 0x7f86e0b69d0f
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"21E9A41","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"21E9425"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"22DE616","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"22DE661"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"1A0356F","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool25_startWorkerThread_inlockEv"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"1A03DC8","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool8scheduleESt8functionIFvvEE"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"1CA119C","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor23scheduleIntoPool_inlockEPNSt7__cxx114listISt10shared_ptrINS1_13CallbackStateEESaIS6_EEERKSt14_List_iteratorIS6_ESD_St11unique_lockISt5mutexE"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"1CA1602","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor23scheduleIntoPool_inlockEPNSt7__cxx114listISt10shared_ptrINS1_13CallbackStateEESaIS6_EEESt11unique_lockISt5mutexE"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"1CA3A79","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor12scheduleWorkERKSt8functionIFvRKNS0_12TaskExecutor12CallbackArgsEEE"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"1CA3B8C","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor14scheduleWorkAtENS_6Date_tERKSt8functionIFvRKNS0_12TaskExecutor12CallbackArgsEEE"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"110AC4B","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl26ReplicationCoordinatorImpl33_scheduleHeartbeatToTarget_inlockERKNS_11HostAndPortEiNS_6Date_tE"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"110C1CB","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl26ReplicationCoordinatorImpl24_handleHeartbeatResponseERKNS_8executor12TaskExecutor25RemoteCommandCallbackArgsEi"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"1C9CD76"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"1CA0523","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor11runCallbackESt10shared_ptrINS1_13CallbackStateEE"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"1CA0A0B"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"19FFD5C","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool10_doOneTaskEPSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"1A0025C","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool13_consumeTasksEv"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"1A00C46","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool17_workerThreadBodyEPS0_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE"},{"b":"5578E03FF000","o":"22F9770"},{"b":"7F86E0E20000","o":"74A4"},{"b":"7F86E0A81000","o":"E8D0F","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.6.5", "gitVersion" : "a20ecd3e3a174162052ff99913bc2ca9a839d618", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.9.0-12-amd64", "version" : "#1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1 (2020-01-20)", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "5578E03FF000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3D1E04FD7A58BDBC54038E20BE5958518DC10D61" }, { "b" : "7FFE3E171000", "path" : "linux-vdso.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5B172541669A56E313A3E8339FBC3418AA6A17DA" }, { "b" : "7F86E1964000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "EAD5FD817712E63C1212D1EE7D7EE1B9C29F93A7" }, { "b" : "7F86E175C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "86B35D63FACD97D22973E99EE9863F7714C4F53A" }, { "b" : "7F86E1558000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DB2CAEEEC37482A98AB1416D0A9AFE2944930DE9" }, { "b" : "7F86E1254000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4E49714C557CE0472C798F39365CA10F9C0E1933" }, { "b" : "7F86E103D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "51AD5FD294CD6C813BED40717347A53434B80B7A" }, { "b" : "7F86E0E20000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "16D609487BCC4ACBAC29A4EAA2DDA0D2F56211EC" }, { "b" : "7F86E0A81000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "775143E680FF0CD4CD51CCE1CE8CA216E635A1D6" }, { "b" : "7F86E1B7B000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "606DF9C355103E82140D513BC7A25A635591C153" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x5578e25e8a41]
 mongod(+0x21E9425) [0x5578e25e8425]
 mongod(_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+0x6) [0x5578e26dd616]
 mongod(+0x22DE661) [0x5578e26dd661]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool25_startWorkerThread_inlockEv+0x99F) [0x5578e1e0256f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool8scheduleESt8functionIFvvEE+0x398) [0x5578e1e02dc8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor23scheduleIntoPool_inlockEPNSt7__cxx114listISt10shared_ptrINS1_13CallbackStateEESaIS6_EEERKSt14_List_iteratorIS6_ESD_St11unique_lockISt5mutexE+0x24C) [0x5578e20a019c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor23scheduleIntoPool_inlockEPNSt7__cxx114listISt10shared_ptrINS1_13CallbackStateEESaIS6_EEESt11unique_lockISt5mutexE+0x52) [0x5578e20a0602]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor12scheduleWorkERKSt8functionIFvRKNS0_12TaskExecutor12CallbackArgsEEE+0x179) [0x5578e20a2a79]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor14scheduleWorkAtENS_6Date_tERKSt8functionIFvRKNS0_12TaskExecutor12CallbackArgsEEE+0x4C) [0x5578e20a2b8c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl26ReplicationCoordinatorImpl33_scheduleHeartbeatToTarget_inlockERKNS_11HostAndPortEiNS_6Date_tE+0x33B) [0x5578e1509c4b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl26ReplicationCoordinatorImpl24_handleHeartbeatResponseERKNS_8executor12TaskExecutor25RemoteCommandCallbackArgsEi+0x11FB) [0x5578e150b1cb]
 mongod(+0x1C9CD76) [0x5578e209bd76]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor11runCallbackESt10shared_ptrINS1_13CallbackStateEE+0x1B3) [0x5578e209f523]
 mongod(+0x1CA0A0B) [0x5578e209fa0b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool10_doOneTaskEPSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE+0x14C) [0x5578e1dfed5c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool13_consumeTasksEv+0xBC) [0x5578e1dff25c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool17_workerThreadBodyEPS0_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x96) [0x5578e1dffc46]
 mongod(+0x22F9770) [0x5578e26f8770]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x74A4) [0x7f86e0e274a4]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x3F) [0x7f86e0b69d0f]
```

What could be the cause here ? From system metrics I do see an anomaly starting from 8:10 AM on the read disk ops & read disk throughput - sudden rise from 150 QPS to 2.5K QPS and from 15 MBps to 60 MBps resulting in a load avg increase from 0.25 to 4.5 on a 4 core box.

Even if the read disk ops and load avg increased massively, would it result in terminating the process ? unable to get any reason from the logs.

Comment: please check ulimit on you machine

Answer (score 0):

Review https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/ carefully, then review https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/. Apply to your installation as appropriate.

> unable to get any reason from the logs.

Your provided log contains the reason:

```
2021-08-29T08:24:17.810+0530 F -        [replexec-210] std::exception::what(): Resource temporarily unavailable
Actual exception type: std::system_error
```

This could have the same cause as earlier errors:

```
2021-08-29T08:24:09.808+0530 I -        [listener] pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
```